# How to achieve hair volume without blow drying?

Tags: hair

I like my undercut, everything is fine. But when I try to get a little bit of volume, just to give some "happiness" into my undercut + slick back, it's impossible.

Is it possible to do without blow drying, because I don't have much time in the morning to do it before the school.
Any help ?

Comment: Hi user27466. Welcome to Lifehacks.StackExchange. We hope you enjoy your stay and look forward to your sharing of questions and answers with us.

Comment: Blow drying is a fast, relatively safe way to dry your hair. You may have already discarded the "best" way to solve your time-limited issue. Even towel-dried hair takes longer and does more damage to the tips of your hair with the friction of the towel. I used a towel when I was younger and… now I'm bald.

Comment: Are you usually washing your hair in the morning, or just getting up and leaving for school?

Comment: There's not enough info here about your routine and hair type to give good advice.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to blow drying is backcombing, but I don't think it'll save you much time.

The basics are easy: you grasp a strand of hair in one hand and with the other repeatedly run a fine comb from the tips back to the roots. This puffs the strand up in a somewhat messy way.

To give your hair more volume, you need to repeat the backcombing all over the area. Then very lightly run the comb over the top layer of hair (root to tip this time) to neaten the look. You can add hair product to keep the volume for longer.

Comment: True. Ruins your hair though

Comment: This can be quick.  Spray with dry shampoo and backcomb with a brush rather than a comb.  You don't need to do much.  Don't backcomb the top layer.  Also try using little or no conditioner and make sure you get all the grease out.  // Alternatively you can get a weave to create volume at the back of the head. // Or wear some kind of pony tail or something with a big hair clip gadget (the kind with the spring).

Answer (score 1):

If you want volume in your hair without blow dry then you should take one lemon juice and two spoon of Apple vinegar mix it in water and use this water while washing
 your hair. After dry you  wil see your hair has natural volume.

Answer (score 0):

Hot rollers.

Get the kind that are big and have a soft, fuzzy coating.  The fuzzy coating is easier on your fingertips so you can roll the hot rollers quickly and without burning yourself.

First thing in the morning, plug in the heater, wait until the indicator says the rollers are warm enough (2 minutes?), roll them in your hair (5-10 min), then go eat and go about your morning routine.  Your hair should be ready in 15-30 minutes depending upon your hair’s length, thickness, and if your hair was wet at all (this works best if your hair is very lightly misted with a spray bottle before rolling).  Takes about 2 min to pull the rollers out.  And, voila!  Fluffy volume!

I did this for years and loved it.  Recently, though, I discovered I could achieve similar results with a flat iron.  If you pull your hair through and twist the iron just right, you can add waves and volume to your hair.  Also, this will last me a few days.  It’s not quick, though (takes about an hour and I have thick, waist length hair), and it’s a bit of a trick to get it right.  But what I love is waking up the next day and all I have to do is finger comb my hair and it’s gorgeous.  Zero maintenance.

Good luck!